# setTimeot wont work

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I am trying to set the element to display: none; after 5 seconds but the function fires immediately, so I wonder what's wrong with the setTimeout.

I have searched alot on the web to find the flaw but every source I go to, they say I should use SetTimeout as I am using it. I would really appreciate any answers.

```js
var sideholder = document.getElementById("intro-holder");
window.onload = function ut() {
   sideholder.style.display = "none";
 }
setTimeout(ut, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the function to be the value of `window.onload` and it will run after the window loads. But, before that happens, the JavaScript runtime will move on to the next line, which is your attempt to run the function named `ut` after 5 seconds, however that name `ut` won't be meaningful at this point because of the way you initially used it.

Change the code to the following so that once that page loads, it will count to 5 seconds and then run your function, which will be declared as a function declaration, rather than a function expression.

Also, you should not scan the DOM for "intro-holder" until the DOM is loaded (depending on where you have this code in your page you may not need to make this change).

```
// Get variables declared, but wait to initialize:
var sideholder = null;
var timer = null;

// When the window reports it is loaded, run a function that initiates the 
// timer. Also, it's always a good idea to set a variable to the integer
// that represents the running timer in case you want to stop the timer 
// later using clearTimeout(timer);
window.onload = function(){

 // Now that the window is loaded, it's safe to go looking for DOM elements
 sideholder = document.getElementById("intro-holder");

 // Start the clock
 timer = setTimeout(ut, 5000);

}

function ut() {
   sideholder.style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: Setting `window.onload` to the integer returned from `setTimeout()` doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Thanks. Time for a caffeine break.

Answer (score 0):

You're using setTimeout correctly, but window.onload is set equal to your ut function, making your element disappear (style:none) on pageload. Then 5 seconds later, ut runs and errors because the element is already hidden. window.onload should be set equal to setTimeout so the browser knows to run it as soon as the page loads. Then the ut function can be defined after. Function ut then runs after 5 seconds.

```js
var sideholder = document.getElementById("intro-holder");

function ut () {
     sideholder.style.display = "none";
  }

window.onload = setTimeout(ut, 5000);
```

```css
#intro-holder{
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  }
```

```html
<div id="intro-holder">
  </div>
```